# Trouble aligning a UIView and a CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cashapelayer

I'm having trouble aligning a `UIView` and a `CAShapeLayer`.

Here is sample code demonstrating the issue:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let square = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        square.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(20*M_PI/180))
        square.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        view.addSubview(square)

        let strokeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        strokeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: square.bounds).CGPath
        strokeLayer.position = square.center
        strokeLayer.setAffineTransform(square.transform)

        strokeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        strokeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        strokeLayer.lineWidth = 1

        view.addSubview(square)
        view.layer.addSublayer(strokeLayer)
    }
}
```

Here's an image of the result:

[image: Result of code in iOS Simulator]

How do I get the two to align?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only change you would need to make is to add:

```
strokeLayer.frame = square.layer.bounds
```

Right after:

```
let strokeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
```

I.e.,

```
let strokeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
strokeLayer.frame = square.layer.bounds
strokeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: square.bounds).CGPath
strokeLayer.position = square.center
strokeLayer.setAffineTransform(square.transform)

strokeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
strokeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
strokeLayer.lineWidth = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you position your shape layer at (0,0)

```
strokeLayer.position = CGPointMake( 0, 0 )
```

Comment: also remove the transform from your shape layer